# Уменьшение изображения на php

Tags: php, изображения

Нашёл в нете решение, вот эта функция:

```
function img_resize($src, $dest, $width, $height, $rgb, $quality) {                                                                                   
if (!file_exists($src)) {
return false;                                             
}
$size = getimagesize($src);

if ($size === false) {
return false;
}

$format = strtolower(substr($size['mime'], strpos($size['mime'], '/')+1));
$icfunc = "imagecreatefrom" . $format;                                    
if (!function_exists($icfunc)) {
return false;                              
}

$x_ratio = $width / $size[0];
$y_ratio = $height / $size[1];
$ratio = min($x_ratio, $y_ratio);
$use_x_ratio = ($x_ratio == $ratio);

$new_width = $use_x_ratio  ? $width  : floor($size[0] * $ratio);
$new_height = !$use_x_ratio ? $height : floor($size[1] * $ratio);
$new_left = $use_x_ratio  ? 0 : floor(($width - $new_width) / 2);
$new_top = !$use_x_ratio ? 0 : floor(($height - $new_height) / 2);

$isrc = $icfunc($src);
$idest = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$white = imagecolorallocate($idest, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
imagefill($idest, 0, 0, $white);
imagecopyresampled($idest, $isrc, $new_left, $new_top, 0, 0,
$new_width, $new_height, $size[0], $size[1]);

imagejpeg($idest, $dest, $quality);

imagedestroy($isrc);
imagedestroy($idest);

return true;
}
```

использую так:

```
img_resize('primer.png', 'new_name_primer.png', 500, 500, '#ffffff', 100);
```

Всё нормально работает, но есть одна проблема... если изображение имеет разрешение например 5000px на 4000px и больше то оно не уменьшается, а если к примеру 3000px на 2500px и меньше то всё нормально происходит, изображение уменьшается, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Проверьте настройки пхп, в частности разрешённый размер обрабатываемых файлов. Скорее всего не разрешается пхп кушать такие большие файлы.

Comment: вылазиет ошибка указывающая на строку $isrc = $icfunc($src); а вот сама ошибка: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 22000 bytes) in /home/c5119/public_html/func.php on line 32

Comment: И какое слово в сообщении об ошибке непонятно?

Comment: мол байты исчерпаны, пытался выделить 22000 байт,так что делать то?

Comment: Увеличивать размер памяти, отведённой для PHP. Следующий вопрос будет "как?", угадал?

Comment: @shol тут ~67МБ не хватает. Нужно больше выделять. я бы 256Мб минимум на такое выделил. 
@klopp затралил парня)))

Comment: Так в первом комментарии же всё сказано, надо иногда с ручника сниматься :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно так же почитать документацию по работе с библиотеками GD и ImageMagic в зависимости от того какой пользуетесь.